# Edge command to display without borders

Tags: command-line, microsoft-edge

I would like to display a Microsoft Edge window without borders, I know that for Internet explorer it's "-k", and in the documentation of edge I found a "--kiosk", I tried this one, but it displays in fullscreen and I can't move the window, anyone knows how to handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to start Edge in kiosk mode which doesn't have borders, but don't want it in fullscreen and want to resize and move the Edge window?

If so, I'm afraid it's impossible. Kiosk mode and fullscreen mode will both open browser in fullscreen, and you can't change the size of the browser window. Then you can't move the window.

The closest solution is using `--app` flag like this `start msedge --app=http://www.somesite.com`. In this situation, the browser window can be resized and moved. It will hide the toolbar, address bar and tabs, but leave the window frame:

[image]

Comment: And is there anyway to hide the topbar ? Even in the Edge parameters ? Or in the regedit maybe ? It's very close to what I need but, that topbar is ruining it all ! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I totally understand what you want, but unfortunately, there's no way to hide the top title bar. If you really need this feature, I suggest that you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. The Edge team will check the feedbacks and improve the product continously. Thanks for your understanding.